# Decompress PNG directly to disk

Tags: ios, png, memory-mapped-files, libpng

I have a large PNG that I want uncompressed to a file, but I don't have the memory capacity on the device to expand the PNG in memory, then to a file.

Is there a native iOS method to uncompress a PNG for each scan line? Alternatives?

Libpng - *Reading image data* - http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.2.5-manual.html#section-3.8

For non-interlaced PNGs

`png_read_rows(png_ptr, row_pointers, NULL, number_of_rows);`

Comment: My Java library PNGJ does that ... in Java. https://code.google.com/p/pngj/

Comment: Thanks- know of an equivalent library for c/c++/objective-c ?

Comment: No. But with libpng you should be able to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

As and idea how to start:

Take a look how is doing Java the png decompressing algorithm. Java should have open-source those files. Maybe has the iOS too idk. Just get the uncompress algorithm idea. It should be around 1k-5k lines of code.

When you know how to do it, than implement at iOS but read a chunk of file and than export to a file, read another chunk and process and export it.  I know it is easy to say and at least theoretically it is working. Maybe is public in some site. [Libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) can be a good starting point.

Png is a looseness compression like zip. There as I have remember runtime is built a data table. Those table depends how big is, maybe need to be swapped to to disk, which will makes longer the decompression process.

Good luck!